# Is there a way of sending/paste a file like .csv to a website with python

Tags: python, csv, web

I'm trying to send/paste a csv to  **http://geojson.io/** so my file contains longitudes and latitudes and I want o get them on that map, if there is any method of doing this please help.

Comment: You probably want to use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) and refer to this
 [article](https://www.qacult.com/blog-details.php?slug=how-to-do-copy-paste-in-browser-using-selenium-using-actions-class&id=37)

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible but with frameworks like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) that help in automation.
Basic workflow for you in this case would be:

- Load CSV in the script and run a loop to iterate over longitudes and latitudes.
- Now load http://geojson.io/ using selenium webdriver and "send_keys" to the respective web elements of the latitude and longitude and submit/search.